# Progress bars not loading individually

Tags: jquery, css, progress-bar

I'm building a page that contains multiple progress bars and these bars have the following issues:

1 - The progress bars load when visible on the page. The problem is they all load at the same time as soon as the first one is visible on the viewport. They should load as they come into the viewport one by one independently.

2 - Also another problem is when I'm in the bottom of the page and refresh the browser the animations only get triggered when I scroll all the way back up to the first bar.

Please have a look at the example:

https://jsfiddle.net/f9c1szxu/

I hope someone could help me with this one. Many thanks!

**JS**

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
  }
  var IsViewed = false;
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if (isScrolledIntoView('.progress-bar') && !IsViewed) {
      $('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function() {
        var progress = $(this);
        var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
        $({
          countNum: 0
        }).animate({
          countNum: percentage
        }, {
          duration: 3500,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function() {
            // What todo on every count
            var pct = '';
            if (percentage == 0) {
              pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
            } else {
              pct = Math.floor(this.countNum + 1) + '%';
            }
            progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width', pct);
          }
        });
      });
      IsViewed = true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: you have same class `progress-bar` for all progress bar. so it happend

Comment: I need to keep the same class. I'm using multiple progress bars in the same page and I don't want to have a different class for each one of them.

Comment: you can add additional class?

Comment: No. I need to keep the same class .progress-bar in all of them.

Comment: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/wN7ah/2119/. It may help

Comment: you keep `.progress-bar`  and add one more class `<div class="progress-bar webdesignprgsbar">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using all progress bar at once, you need to process them one by one and each progress bar you process add a class to it to not process it again

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
var IsViewed = false;
$(document).scroll(function() {

  $('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]:not(.viewed)').each(function() {
    var progress = $(this);
    if (isScrolledIntoView(progress.parent('.progress-bar'))) {

      var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
      progress.addClass('viewed');
      $({
        countNum: 0
      }).animate({
        countNum: percentage
      }, {
        duration: 3500,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
          // What todo on every count
          var pct = '';
          if (percentage == 0) {
            pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
          } else {
            pct = Math.floor(this.countNum + 1) + '%';
          }
          progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width', pct);
        }


      });

    }
  });

  IsViewed = true;

});
```

```css
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 400px;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 2.0rem;
  height: 5.0rem;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #000;
}

.progress-bar:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.bar-label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.bar-percentage {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4rem;
  right: 0;
}

.bar-container {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #EFEFEF;
}

.progress-bar.thick-bar .bar-container,
.progress-bar.thick-bar .bar {
  height: 1.0rem;
}

.bar {
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
  Scroll down
</h2>

<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="95"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="95"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="95"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="95"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<h2>
  Scroll down
</h2>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="95"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="95"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="95"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="bar-label">Web Design</div>
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="95"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Updated JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f9c1szxu/2/)